# How to get the specific index from sum of the list over this IF-condition?

Tags: python

I would like to sum the value by each index backward until its gonna reach the 'cap' and get an index from the last value and print it with the iterative index x(Actually, x should start from 1)

```
total = 0 
cap = 30   
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
myArray.reverse()

for x in range(len(myArray)):
    total = total + myArray[x]
    if total >= cap:
        print(x,total)
    break
```

Comment: Instructions unclear

Comment: Indent break inside if statement

Comment: I have a list of number. I would like to build the sum of the list until it will reach 'cap = 30' and get an index from the last index. For example 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 is over 30. In this case I would like to get an index from 7

Comment: what do you mean by the iterative index? is it the same as the the list?

Answer (score 2):

No need to `reverse()`, you can iterate backward: ( I moved `break` inside the condition)

```
total = 0
cap = 30
myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for x in range(len(myArray) - 1, - 1, -1):
    total += myArray[x]
    if total >= cap:
        print(x, total)
        break
```

Output :  `6 34`

Comment: What are -1 stand for?

Comment: @ChirayuBall Because indexes of a list start from `0` to `len(lst) -1` we should provide `start:  len(myArray) - 1` , `stop : -1` (this is because stop is not included so ends with `0` which we are looking for), and then `step :-1` (for backward iteration)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation

Comment: @ChirayuBall Happy to help, In stackoverflow you can accept one answer which you find most helpful by click on the "check" icon which is located below the upvoting and downvoting section in answers post.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the other answer it is the indentation of `break`.

Here is an alternative using `enumerate` and `reverse`:

```
total = 0 
cap = 30   
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for idx, val in enumerate(reversed(myArray)):
    total += val
    if total >= cap:
        print(idx, total)
        break
```

On the second read I am unsure what index you want to have. Array position or number of iterations in the for loop?

Comment: @Ade_1 thanks, fixed. That was a fragment of an old solution, as it is for me not completly clear if of wants array or loop index

Comment: great!, i think your solution is quite efficient, especially when looping with indexes

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you placed `break` outside `if` condition,

```
total = 0 
cap = 30   
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
myArray.reverse()

for x in range(len(myArray)):
    total = total + myArray[x]
    if total >= cap:
        print(x,total)
        break
```

**Output:**

```
3 34
```